# Can smoke particles in Python(Blender) follow curve

Tags: python, blender, particle-system

Is there a way to make smoke particles in Blender/Python follow a specific curve or at least its aproximation? (Wind is not an answer to my question)

Answer (score 0):

While the smoke simulation doesn't appear to follow a curve guide, the particle system does. You could setup a particle system that follows a curve guide and use the particles as the flow source for the smoke emission.

Instead of using the particles as the source for smoke you could use particles to simulate smoke. Using blender internal a halo material can be setup to give a smoke like result. In cycles the new point density (added in 2.76) can give a similar result. [This a short example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWD_eJwlOpc) of using point density in cycles. [This conference video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJietAeINTc) includes a short tutorial on using it starting at about 13:00